# async onSubmit to wait for state to change

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, state

I have a form that runs a function onSubmit. The function (an action reducer) calls an async function that stores the data using a reducer and then changes some state (doesnt return anything). I need to see the result if this function (check state) to choose the next action. I am doing as follows:

```
    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  
    await addPlanner(planner); // Reducer Action that changes state field called error initially set to null
   
    if (error) {
      setAlert(error, 'error');
    } else {
      setAlert('Planner Added', 'success');
    }
   clearForm();
};
```

The current behaviour:

- When addPlanner runs successfully I get planner Added Alert (because error does not change and thus stays in the initial state null). When It fails the Planner added alert appears again and then state is changed (but if function not waiting for it)
- Is this possible to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Effect hook, which calls upon when error state is changed. Also remove the code from the place where you have added currently

```
React.useEffect(
        () => {
          if (error) {
           setAlert(error, 'error');
         }  else {
           setAlert('Planner Added', 'success');
          }
        },
        [error]
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Raghevender. This works fine the issue is that it shows the alert when the component is loaded. Is there a way to avoid that? Actually this is why i didnt think of useEffect to start with!
Thx again

Comment: Hi Again,
I solved this by checking another success state called add. This worked great. Thank you so much for the help and the prompt reply.
    React.useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      setAlert(error.errors[0].msg, 'error');
    } else if (add) {
      setAlert('Planner Added', 'success');
    }
  }, [error]);

Comment: Ah i did but i am a new user and with my reputation my upvotes dont count :(

Comment: Oh.. its ok.. Thanks :)